# regex match first occurrence of a single character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'll make this extremely simple

I have a function that comes across a string as such by design: `water 'thing one'`

I need to split this string by the first space, since there are spaces elsewhere.

I've tried many regex expressions like `/ .*? /`, but they can only match two consecutive spaces.

How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do spaces inside single quotes count as legitimate possible places to make the first split?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not looking to split between 'thing' and 'one' if that's what you mean. I'm trying to match the space after 'water'.

Comment: `'thing one' water` ... how do we split this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I might be confused at what you’re asking, but I want to split `water ‘thing one’` into `water` and `’thing one’`, ie- by the first occurrence of a space in the string.

Comment: Hmmm...you seem unable to answer my questions.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry for the inconvenience, it’s late for me and I sorta don’t understand exactly what you need precisions on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228776/discussion-between-uncannyorange-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: I have given a literal answer to your question below.  My fear below is that now you are going to come out with many edge cases, hence my questions above in the comments.

Comment: @uncannyorange Tim is asking if it's the space you're looking to split on or whether you're trying to get the quoted section. What exactly are you after? In an example of `'thing one' water`, would you be seeking `'thing` and `one' water` or `'thing one'` and `water`? That's what Tim is asking you to clarify. Regex works given a pattern. He's trying to identify that pattern and any points of failure for samples you haven't yet presented or thought of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the portion of the string before and after the first space, you could use regex replacement here:

```js
var input = "water 'thing one'";
var first = input.replace(/[ ].*$/, "");
var second = input.replace(/^\S*[ ]/, "");
console.log("first part:  " + first);
console.log("second part: " + second);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture them using [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with this regex:

```
/(.*?) (.*)/
```

```js
const text = "water 'thing one'";
const [, first, second] = text.match(/(.*?) (.*)/);
console.log('first:', first);
console.log('second:', second);
```